# Force WooCommerce Email Templates

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We trying to force the WooCommerce email templates to be used throughout the website, instead of the default WordPress email templates.

So for an example, if a customer selects Forgot Password on our WordPress login, then the WooCommerce email template should still be sent to the users email address.

How can we update this functionality?

Kind regards,
Dale

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer my own question.

I managed to find a workaround solution.

I've installed the following plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-better-emails/

The plugin allows you to customize the WordPress email template.

It's not the best solution, but it works for now.